# PHPMAILER Sending Email in attached file

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, html-email

```
<?php    
include('phpmailer.php');
class Mail extends PhpMailer
{
    // Set default variables for all new objects
    public $From     = 'noreply@domain.com';
    public $FromName = SITETITLE;
    public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    public $Mailer   = 'isSMTP';
    public $SMTPAuth = true;
    public $Username = 'email@gmail.com';
    public $Password = 'password';
    public $SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    public $WordWrap = 75;

    public function subject($subject)
    {
        $this->Subject = $subject;
    }

    public function body($body)
    {
        $this->Body = $body;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
        $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
        return parent::send();
    }
}
```

I am Using this Code for Email.php file and it works but it sends Mail in Attachment Not in Normal Form...
[Email Attachment Showing in Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi6UD.png)

[Email Attachment Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seKgS.png)

Here is link where i am using it for verification purposes.

```
http://monthlyreport.ultimatefreehost.in
```

At index.php I am using Like this

```
 //send email
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
            $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at demo site.</p>
            <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
            <p>Regards Site Admin</p>";

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->subject($subject);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=joined');
            exit;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal form"? You are not calling addAttachment(), so you won't have any attachments.

Comment: like a mail comes,but it is coming in attachment

Comment: @Synchro,Sir Can you suggest me What is Problem!!!

Comment: Are you using latest PHPMailer? It looks like you based your code on an obsolete example.

Comment: @Synchro Sir i have Checked its Version is 5.2.7

Comment: Right, so how about you check for the latest version? Why are you not using composer?

Comment: Sir,Can you help me in fixing???

Comment: Is the text "Get premium hosting from https://ifastnet.com, free domain name, unlimited disk pace,,,, far too many features to list." being added to the bottom of the email by your mail server or your client? If it's the server, I'd hazard a guess it's breaking the MIME encoding because the text is after the final MIME boundary.

Comment: Yeah Sir its coming in each email

Comment: @MattRaines do you have any idea regarding the problem what i am having currently???

Comment: If this text is added by your mail server, my guess is it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Any Other way to Solve????

Answer (score -1):

Your functions should return the values.

Use `return $this->Body = $body;` at the end of `body()`, and similarly do it for the other functions as well.

Comment: Sir i tried it Now and now Its HTTP500 error ...Please check and suggest some thing else

Comment: Try by passing the values directly, like  $mail->Subject = "$subject"; and 
    $mail->Body = "$body";

Comment: This is the closest thing I've seen to superstitious code! Just wrong, will achieve nothing.